# Cell from dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier in cellForRowAtIndexPath not showing up until scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have the function below to populate a tableview. I'm making an array and getting text and an image to display in a cell. When that information is loaded, the cell is supposed to display. However, cells won't display until I scroll. What is the issue and how can I fix it? I've look at other questions but they can't seem to answer my question, or maybe I just don't understand what they're saying.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PreviousSongCell

    var song : PreviousSong
    song = self.previousSongs[indexPath.row]

    if (song.artist != "") {
        tableView.userInteractionEnabled = true

        cell.song.text = song.song
        cell.artist.text = "by " + song.artist
        cell.time.text = song.time
        cell.art.image = song.art

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        cell.alpha = 0

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.15, animations: { cell.alpha = 1 })

    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Did this function being called when it's first displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this after your data is loaded:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```